# See all reminders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I like to set reminders with Cortana every once in a while. However, sometimes I lose track of what I have set Cortana to remind me for. Is there an easy and quick way, to see all the reminders I set with Cortana?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in Microsoft's post "[Get reminders from Cortana](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4045913/cortana-get-reminders)", open the Cortana window and choose Notebook > Reminders for that list.